# Characteristics of $c$-vectors of acyclic cluster algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, cluster-algebras

In Speyer and Thomas's work, [Acyclic Cluster Algebras Revisited](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.0277v1.pdf) the characteristics of $c$-vectors of cluster algebras with the $B$-matrix of the initial seed acyclic are given in Theorem 1.4. Do we have similar results for acyclic cluster algebra in general (i.e. The $B$-matrix of some seed is acyclic but the $B$-matrix of the original seed might not)?

In particular I'm interested in the case where the original $B$-matrix is induced by the cyclic quiver of $n$ vertices.